# How to get constraint matrix after presolving in PySCIPOpt

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, scip

I have a `pyscipopt.Model` variable `model`, encoding an integer program with linear constraints.

I want to evaluate some solution on all rows of the constraint matrix. The only way I thought of is to use `model.getSolVal()` to get solution values on modified variables, and compute the dot product with the rows of the modified constraint matrix manually.

The following snippet extracts the nonzero coefficients of a constraint in the model:

```
constr = model.getConss()[0]
coeff_dict = model.getValsLinear(constr)
```

It runs fine before presolving, but after presolving (or just optimizing) I get the following error

```
Warning: 'coefficients not available for constraints of type ', 'logicor'.
```

My current solution is to disable presolving completely, in which case the variables aren't modified. Can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to do something with the row activities and not just check whether your solution is feasible?

`getValsLinear` is only usable for linear constraints. In presolving SCIP upgrades linear constraints to some more specialized constraint types (in your case logicor).

There exists a function in SCIP called `SCIPgetConsVals` that does what you want `getValsLinear` to do (it gets you the values for all constraints that have a linear representation). However, that function is not wrapped in `PySCIPopt` yet.

You can easily wrap that function yourself (and even head over to https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt and create a Pull-request).
The other option is to read a settings file that forbids the linear constraints from being upgraded.

```
constraints/linear/upgrade/logicor = FALSE 
constraints/linear/upgrade/indicator = FALSE
constraints/linear/upgrade/knapsack = FALSE
constraints/linear/upgrade/setppc = FALSE
constraints/linear/upgrade/xor = FALSE
constraints/linear/upgrade/varbound = FALSE
```

would be the settings you need. That way you still have presolving just without constraint upgrades.

Comment: I want "how far is the solution from violating the constraint". 
I'll try to include this settings file first.

Comment: There also exists a function that does exactly this in SCIP `SCIPgetFeasibilityLinear` (if you know that all your constraint are linear). It is also not yet wrapped in pyscipopt, however.